# Google Maps API returned status 'REQUEST_DENIED' in perl

Tags: perl

I am a new one to Perl, While I am trying to write the code to print latitudes and longitude of a location using Geo::Coder::Google it returns "Google Maps API returned status 'REQUEST_DENIED'" error message.

Can anyone help me to fix that issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Geo::Coder::Google;

my $geocoder = Geo::Coder::Google->new( apiver => 3 );
my $info = $geocoder->geocode( location => 'Bangalore,Karnataka, India' );

my $location = $info->{geometry}{location};

printf "%s %s\n", $location->{lat}, $location->{lng};
```

I expect to print latitudes and longitude of Bangalore.

Answer (score 5):

You need to obtain an API key and provide it to the module.

---

The following is the complete response from Google:

```
{
   status => 'REQUEST_DENIED',
   error_message => 'You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account',
   results => [],
}
```

(I've obtained this by adding some code to the module.)

The error message reads as follows:

> You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

[The link from the error message](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account) provides instructions on getting an API key if you don't have one, and about properly setting up your account if you do.

[The module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Geo::Coder::Google::V3) specifies how to provide your API key.